# Is there any way to reload or refresh the JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am new to java. I am trying to reload Jpanel with a click event.
i tried repaint() but it didnt work.
I have following code:
mainview.java

public class MainView extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    viewPanel p1;

```
public MainView() {
    initComponents();
    p1=new viewPanel();

    MainPanel.setLayout(layout);
    GridBagConstraints c=new GridBagConstraints();
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=0;
    MainPanel.add(p1,c);

}
```

}
private void btnOpenPanelActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    p1.setVisible(true);
}
```

please suggest

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use revalidate method

```
JPanel j1=new JPanel();
j1.revalidate();
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I tried this as well but it not working. is there any other way to reload/ refresh jpanel